# Using slf4j with c3p0 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, slf4j, c3p0

I'm trying to get my c3p0 to log to slf4j (log4j backend).

The [c3p0 documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging), says that this property will do the trick:

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog
```

However, c3p0 gives the error on startup:

```
Tried without success to load the following MLog classes:
    com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog
```

I have included Hibernate c3p0, using Gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '4.3.6.Final'
```

It includes a c3p0 0.9.2.1 jar, which *does not have* this MLog class. So i explicitly include c3p):

```
compile group: 'c3p0', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.1.2'
```

...which does have the class, but c3p0 still refuses to load it (same error) - i guess because of a c3p0 version conflict, the old version is ignored.

Not sure where to go from here; any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slf4j support is a c3p0 0.9.5 feature.

please try upgrading to c3p0 0.9.5-pre9.

Comment: Hi Steve, is this hosted in a repo somewhere i can point my Gradle to?

Comment: yes. [groupId: com.mchange, artifactId: c3p0, version: 0.9.5-pre9]

Comment: there's a performance issue (unnecessary allocation of Strings) with slf4j support prior to versions 0.9.5.2. please try to upgrade to  [groupId: com.mchange, artifactId: c3p0, version: 0.9.5.2] if you are having c3p0 log to slf4j. sorry!

Comment: Details about how to setup logging for c3p0:
https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging